# Blade include issue

Tags: laravel, include

I'm having problem with @include. Fillig a table with user data, I want to @include a little delete-form on each record.

The problem is that in the first row the form is being included without the  tag, still in other rows the form includes properly

Any ideas, please?

View code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-head-fixed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @forelse ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
                @can('user-index')
                <a href="{{ route('users.show', $user) }}" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" title="View">
                    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                </a>
                @endcan
                @can('user-edit')
                <a href="{{ route('users.edit', $user) }}" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" title="Edit">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
                @endcan
                <!-- -->
                @include('users.partials.delete')
                <!-- -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @empty
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">No users in this role</td>
    </tr>
    @endforelse
</tbody>
</table>
```

The form code:

```
@can('user-delete')
<form action="{{ route('users.destroy', $user) }}" method="POST" onsubmit="if (!confirm('Really delete user {{ $user->name }} <{{ $user->email }}> ?')) return false;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
</form>
@endcan
```

I use spatie permission.
I've tried view:clear and cache:clear.

UPD

The result HTML is:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-head-fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Enos Lueilwitz</td>
      <td>dagmar26@example.org</td>
      <td>
        <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
          <a href="http://dev.local/users/2" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" title="View">
            <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="http://dev.local/users/2/edit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" title="Edit">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
          </a>

          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="GNAt0zsQim0JovKMWphVgWYY0g1L6UQCAuzznThj">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
          </button>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mr. Favian Rippin PhD</td>
      <td>willms.gardner@example.net</td>
      <td>
        <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
          <a href="http://dev.local/users/51" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" title="View">
            <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="http://dev.local/users/51/edit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" title="Edit">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
          </a>
          <form action="http://dev.local/users/51" method="POST" onsubmit="if (!confirm('Really delete user Mr. Favian Rippin PhD <willms.gardner@example.net> ?')) return false;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="GNAt0zsQim0JovKMWphVgWYY0g1L6UQCAuzznThj">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete">
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You may see that there is no  tag in the very first table row (search for fas fa-trash-alt).

I tried to take @can() out of the partial and put to the main template - nothing's changed.

Comment: Add @can('user-delete') inthe main blade and then @include form there

Comment: Tnx for comment. Nothing happens. In the very 1st row the <form> tag is missing, in others all fine.

Comment: I even tried to get rid of @can('user-delete')  at all - no result. The first table row doesn't have <form>.

WTF?